# Given an image of bill, how will you identify that from which store it is and what all items are purchased?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

Suppose, I have image of bill of any shopping mall and I want to find out name of store from where i purchased all items and all items that purchased. So, Using image procssing and Machine Learning how I can find ?

Comment: Great question... so what have you tried so far? [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1 : Separate words and background. 
  1-1 : use Threshold , Filter , etc ...
  1-2 : CNN is also good for this. (like Fastest RCNN ) 
Step 2 : Extract words position and width height. maybe If you need align or something else.
Step 3 : Classify words. 
  3-1 : You extract feature from words image. or use deep learning model for automatically extract deep feature. 
  3-2 : You need to use market name and product name datas for training classifier.
  3-3 : Tree base classifier or SVM is good for this problem. because classify criteria is variety if bill.